# How can I sort vector of nested pairs <pair <pair <int, int>, int> > when the sort key is first element then the second

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

How can I sort the vector when the sort key is the first element of the nested pair then the second element of the nested pair and If the elements in the nested pair are tied then the sort key would be in order of increasing of the second element of the pair.

Here is my code so far:

```
 vector <pair <pair <int, int>, int> > vec (101);
                for(int x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
                {
                        vec[x].first.first = 0; // problems
                        vec[x].first.second = -1; // penalty
                        vec[x].second = 100 - x; // index
                }
```

Comment: This seems like a book-keeping nightmare. Why not use structs/classes to better organize your data?

Comment: @CoryKramer I think this way is easier for me plus I was trying to use multi-fields sorting or whatever it's called ;-;

Comment: @BasmaAshour Why [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with custom sorting functor, doesn't work for you?

Comment: Default comparer seems to do the job.

Comment: Well, std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); is working just fine. Thanks all for help.